# Getting comments on all pulled commits in git

Tags: git

I'm using git to manage my project. As a part of the nightly build I have a script that pulls the changes and compiles them. I want to get all the comments for all the commits that were pulled in order to make a readable changelog. 
My assumption is that the commit comments are all good of course.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the following to compare two branches (or commits)

```
git log --oneline --abbrev=10 master..develop > changelog.txt
```

That will output something like...

```
bb210b5a93 Made some changes
2ce854f780 Made some more changes
```

...and put them in `changelog.txt`

**UPDATED**

```
git rev-parse HEAD # returns current git commit hash
```

You could use the output of that before you git pull to use the original commit to compare against.

Comment: So I need master..origin/master?

Comment: master will probably be the same as origin/master once you pull.

Comment: Check my update... you could use `git rev-parse HEAD` and then pull. After you pull you would use `git log --oneline --abbrev=10 <output of git rev-parse>..HEAD`

Comment: Just use `master@{1}..master` for the revision range.

Answer (score 1):

Do this right after `git pull`:

```
$ git log ORIG_HEAD..
```